# SigComparison in quantsrat r package is not changing according to lt or gt but as order the columns are input as arguments

Tags: r, quantstrat

test_1 and test_2 below produces the same result and test_3 changes the result but not respecting the lt releationship, only because of the different order in the "columns" argument.

````
add.signal(
  strategy     = strategy.st, 
  name         = "sigComparison",
  arguments    = list(
    columns = c("SMA35", "SMA10")
  ),
  relationship = "gt",
  label        = "test_1"
)
add.signal(
  strategy     = strategy.st, 
  name         = "sigComparison",
  arguments    = list(
    columns = c("SMA35", "SMA10")
  ),
  relationship = "lt",
  label        = "test_2"
)

add.signal(
  strategy     = strategy.st, 
  name         = "sigComparison",
  arguments    = list(
    columns = c("SMA10", "SMA35")
  ),
  relationship = "lt",
  label        = "test_3"
)
```
````